# Hide DIV with Multiple Styles in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How would I hide a DIV with an ID and the ID has 2 classes? (Code below)

```
<div id="ship" class="block">

#ship, #Payment {width:360px;float: left; margin-right:10px;}

#ship .subhead, #Payment .subhead {margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 5px;}

#ship table, #Payment table, #updatePanel2 table {width:100%;}
```

Comment: I cannot make anything out of this, can you be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select an element which has both of those classes then simply chain them like this.

```
$('#ship.block.subhead').hide();
```

Note that there are no spaces between the id and any of the classes.

Comment: Thanks @holodoc. It does not hide the DIV. The text in the DIV is dynamically placed by ASPX Code.

Comment: That's another issue that is completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Just want to know if the DIV and contents will not be hidden using JQuery if it contains text dynamically?